If $X$ is sub-Gaussian random variable with variance proxy $\sigma^2$, how to show that $E\{ \exp( t X^2) \} \leq (1 - 2 t \sigma^2)^{-1/2}$?
If $X$ is sub-Gaussian random variable with variance proxy $\sigma^2$, i.e., $E(X) = 0$ and $E\{ \exp(s X) \} \leq \exp( \frac{\sigma^2 s^2}{2} )$ for $\forall s \in \mathbb{R}$, then how to show that $E\{ \exp( t X^2) \} \leq (1 - 2 t \sigma^2)^{-1/2}$ for $t < (2 \sigma^2)^{-1}$?
My intuition is that sub-Gaussian is the random variable with tails similar or lighter than Gaussian distribution.
So I guess that $E\{ \exp( t X^2) \} \leq E [ \exp\{ t (\sigma Z)^2\} ]$ should hold for $Z \sim N(0,1)$ and $E [ \exp\{ t (\sigma Z)^2\} ] = (1 - 2 t \sigma^2)^{-1/2}$ with $t < (2 \sigma^2)^{-1}$.
However, I can not rigorously prove it.

You have just to use the integral representation
$$e^{tX^2}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{u\sqrt{2t}X-\frac{u^2}{2}}\frac{du}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$ and Fubini.
Edit:
Oh, I missed the point:  what to do if $t<0$? Things are more difficult and the proof should involve complex variables  for showing that $E(e^{sX})\leq e^{s^2/2}$ implies that $f(s)=e^{-s^2/2}-E(\cos sX)\geq 0.$ I will think about it...

Thank you so much!

Do you know how to prove the result when $t < 0$?
